# Drag and touch other div elements

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, multi-touch

I m working on an App - 
*Where we need to drag an element by touch.- I have done that event. 
* After that we have to drag and touch other div class elements to open a hyperlink ?

```
head.js("js/jquery.min.js","js/ui.js","js/touch.js", function (){
   $(".box_hand").draggable({revert:true});
});
```

Comment: What is this code , how can anyone understand what you are trying to ask , please describe ? Nobody would be able to help you otherwise:|

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i see you are loading elements into the head section, once they are loaded, you make an element draggable. For doing something on drop for example:

```
//supposing you heve a div#droppable in your html
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    //open a link:
    document.location.href="deep_space.html";
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt response, i have to //$(".box_hand") use this class to drag and drop on three diff class 's.

Comment: sorry, can you please explain, do you mean you need to drag a div over $(".box_hand") and trigger a location change?